# IJavaProject without Eclipse Environment in JDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have an exported Eclipse Java Project in my server and I want to be able to compile the project and use `ASTParser` with JDT.

I'm able to compile the project using `BatchCompiler`, however it runs on console and gives me `PrintWriter`s instead of an array of problems and errors. Also I want to be able to use proposals in Eclipse and `BatchCompiler` didn't built for this purpose.

Therefore I tried to use `ASTParser`, it can be used with either `char[]` or `ICompilationUnit`. `CompletionProposalCollector` and `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.Compiler` needs `ICompilationUnit` so I have to create an `ICompilationUnit` which only can be created by an IJavaProject (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/2012/eclipse_workspace.pdf) in order to be able to use these features.

It seems the only way to create `IJavaProject` is to use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()`, however it returns `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.` on my computer and it seems the reason is that the program that I coded is not an Eclipse plug-in.

Is there any way to create IJavaProject without Eclipse environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you are trying to do more than just parsing, you actually want to get some form of content assist.

I'm afraid that you're asking for too much.  There is no simple way to get the power and flexibility of JDT outside of a running Eclipse instance (believe me, I've tried).  There's no simple way, but if you are brave and strong willed, you can one of try following:

1. Run a headless Eclipse on your server that works on top of an actual workspace.  This would be the easiest to implement, but would be the most resource intensive and least flexible way of doing things.
2. Use the jdt core jar, and create alternate implementations of the IResource hierarchy, and the parts of JFace that are used by the the parser and the CompletionEngine.  This would likely be the most feature-rich way to go, but also the most brittle.  I can't guarantee that this would work as you may need to create some very complex stubs for internal Eclipse non-API classes.
3. Avoid the CompletionEngine and the ASTParser entirely and just use the batch compiler. You would then need to provide an alternate implementation of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment`.  This implementation would be able to find types, files, and compilation units in your actual project structure. You'd need to reimplement support for content assist, but this would most likely work reasonably well.

I am actually fairly interested in doing something like this (but I lack the time to do it).  If you are seriously considering creating a headless JDT that can run on a server, feel free to ask for more information.  I am quite familiar with JDT internals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems the best way is the third one. BatchCompiler is good enough to compile the project; I can find all methods and classes using reflections but the problem is AFAIK, there is now way to find out local variable except using ASTParser. (The other hacky way is using regex but I think it wouldn't be efficient) Do you know how I can handle this problem?

Comment: Using the batch compiler only, there is no way to find local variables since they are not stored in the class file.  My suggestion was not actually to use the batch compiler, but rather to invoke a pseudo-compilation using `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler`. You just need to provide your own implementations of all the constructor parameters (the most tricky of which is the name environment). You then want to call `resolve(ICompilationUnit, boolean, boolean, boolean)` on it.  The result will be a fully parsed AST. (but a different AST from the one you get from ASTParser).

Comment: +1 I like the headless approach. It should be possible to remote-control Eclipse from a plugin: Write a plugin that accepts commands from a web browser or use https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control as a starting point.

Comment: @AaronDigulla AFAIK, Eclipse doesn't work in console mode so I need to install a GUI which is a overhead in production server. Also, it makes it hard to control the workspace environment as Andrew said.

Comment: Eclipse works without a UI; how do you think they run all the tests on their CI server? One problem will be to replace the existing Java editor with a remote, web-based one, though. The `StyledText` API is quite hostile and deeply ingrained in the Eclipse code.

Comment: Have you heard of RAP?  This is a technology to that allows you to run an eclipse instance and interact with it through a browser. It's not meant for editor apps, so I don't know if it is appropriate for what you are doing, but it is very cool technology.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I took a look at RAP but it seems an UI toolkit for rich web applications and it doesn't provide such feature. Actually the purpose of RAP seems different then the thing that I want.
BTW, I have written a simple program to compile any java file with compiler.resolve on the fly as you suggested. I can manually get methods, fields using reflections but do you know how I can implement content assist feature of Eclipse? It seems many classes use Eclipse's UI package and I couldn't find any example on the internet.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Actually I don't much thing about JDT, I just tried to run Eclipse on my server and searched on Google about this issue. Still, I'm not able to run Eclipse on my server; however I think that it would be overhead to run Eclipse instances on the server, It would be OK if there are one person that will work on a Java project in the website but when there are multiple users that works on their Java project at the same time, it can be a problem and I may need to run multiple eclipse instances. The thing is that workspaces are distributed, not centralized.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem. Here is how to use `ASTParser` without Eclipse (it just needs the core JDT JAR on the classpath): http://blog.pdark.de/2010/11/05/using-eclipse-to-parse-java-code/

Comment: The current version of program is similar to your example and when I use char[] as source of ASTParser it creates CompilationUnit and I couldn't compile the project or use proposals with it.

Comment: To use the Proposals API, you need a workspace. There are just too many dependencies to untangle it. Maybe I can help if you'd explain what you need to achieve. Why is the AST not enough?

Comment: I'm trying to make something like an online Java Web IDE. AST is more like an analyzing tool; however I need a tool that can simulate Eclipse's behaviour.

Comment: The directory structure in the remote server will be same as Eclipse's workspaces. I'm looking for something that is like just passing the directory path to the getWorkspace method (something like ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace("/home/user/javaproject")) as a parameter to create a workspace object.

Comment: "online Java Web IDE" -> Take a look at project Orion (http://www.eclipse.org/orion/).

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik Orion is not a Java IDE ( http://planetorion.org/news/2012/07/orion-is-not-a-java-ide/)

Comment: My point is that if you are considering building a Java IDE for the web browser, you would be well served by starting with Orion as your foundation. It provides structure, such as workspace, project, etc. that you will need. The stuff that you are asking about...

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik thanks for your advice. I took a look at Orion's source code and it doesn't even use any code written for Eclipse. I'm planning to keep everything simple in frontend so I won't use anything except a file tree and a code editor which is easy to implement using opensource syntax highlighters.

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at the Orion editor, which can be consumd independently from the rest of Orion. IMO, it is the best open source HTML5 editor out there. And it has a nice eclipsy feel. (Disclaimer: I am an Orion committer and have worked on the editor component)

Comment: I like the minimalist design of Orion however the editor doesn't seem much qualified as the other alternatives like ACE editor, also I already know how I can use ACE editor but I'm not really familiar to that editor. :/ BTW, do you guys think to implement Java support into the Orion?